# change django view context based on template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm wondering if there is a way to change `django view` context based on template (I've no idea if it's possible)

I'm building a chat application where I loop through all the thread messages and I'm looping through all images that if the image message id equals to message id to show the message related  image. It's something like this

```
..
{% for message in chatmessages %}
    <p>{{ message.message }}</p>
    {% for img in images %}
        {% if img.message.id == message.id %}
           <img src="{{ img.image.url }}">
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

and the same for attachments.
I'm sending these context from my view

```
    context = {
        "me": me,
        "threads": threads,
        "other_user": other_user,
        "chatmessages": ChatMessage.objects.filter(thread=thread.id),
        "images": MultipleImage.objects.all(),
        "attachments": MultipleAttchment.objects.all(),
    }
```

Any better way to reduce my looping in template for a better functionality!?
here is my `models.py`

```
...
class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField(null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    voice = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_voice_dir, blank=True, null=True)

class MultipleImage(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey('ChatMessage', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_img_dir, blank=True, null=True)

class MultipleAttchment(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(ChatMessage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_att_dir, blank=True, null=True)
...
```

looking for a better way :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to match related object like this, Django can do it for you. Try something like this:

```
{% for message in chatmessages %}
    <p>{{ message.message }}</p>
    {% for img in message.multipleimage_set.all %}
        <img src="{{ img.image.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here what we have done is that we have used the relation between the `Message` and `MultipleImage` to fetch the related images from the database.
**multipleimage_set** is just the model name in lower case with **_set** appended, you can change this if you set a **related_name** attribute in your ForeignKey like so:

```
message = models.ForeignKey('ChatMessage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
```

Now we can write `{% for img in message.images.all %}` if we want to.

Comment: Thanks sir yeah it's working like a charm :)